# INSERT INTO a table with UNIQUE INDEX for two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, mysql-error-1062, unique-index

I have a simple tag_map table as

```
CREATE TABLE tag_map
(
tag_map_id mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
post_id mediumint(7) unsigned REFERENCES posts(post_id),
tag_id mediumint(7) unsigned REFERENCES tags(tag_id),
UNIQUE INDEX (post_id,tag_id),
PRIMARY KEY(tag_map_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

I added `UNIQUE INDEX` to avoid duplicate pairs of a tag associated to a post. Now when I try to add new enteries as

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO (post_id,tag_id) VALUES (post1_id,tag1_id), (post1_id, tag2_id),...
```

I will receive an error

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '16777215' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

but when I `SELECT` WHERE tag_map_id='16777215'; this belongs to a different tag and post.

Where did I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

Your PK's mediumint max value of 16777215 has been reached.

Alter to int or above

Comment: very subtle look at the issue! many thanks for explicit answer!

Comment: Well, here's to you when it pokes you like a needle in the eye and isn't subtle at all, good travels :)

Answer (score 0):

`tag_map_id` is the primary key for the table and can't be duplicated.  Check `SELECT MAX(tag_map_id) FROM tag_map;` and the value of `AUTO_INCREMENT` in `SHOW CREATE TABLE  tag_map;`. The second value should be greater than the first. Sometimes these can get out of sync.

If the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value is less than the maximum `tag_map_id`, just do `ALTER TABLE`tag_map`AUTO_INCREMENT=x;`where `x` is one greater than `MAX(tag_map_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `tag_map_id` is declared as the table `PRIMARY KEY`. You may never, ever, ever have a duplicate primary key. It doesn't matter which tag and post the second row belongs to: it has the same primary key.

You will need to alter your schema if you want two items with the same `tag_map_id`, but it's more likely you've made a logic error in what you are trying to accomplish.